# I want to use SPFolder.Files.Add this sharepoint method to add files in document library with an additional string parameter but not finding any way

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I want to upload a document through the following code in the sharepoint document library 
The issue is that the code work fine but i just want an addtitional sting parameter to be passed with the method say liitle descrptn abt file and also want to retrive the same while i will show the files in the gridview
So i just want to know that how to pass an addtional string paratemer 
as these are all sharepoint methods i can modify it and same time i want to use the byte stream only
Some one kindly help

```
System.IO.Stream strm = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
byte[] byt = new byte[
Convert.ToInt32(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength)];
strm.Read(byt, 0, Convert.ToInt32(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength));
strm.Close();
SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
SPWeb objWeb = site.OpenWeb();
SPFolder mylibrary = objWeb.Folders["UploadedDocs"];
objWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPFile file = mylibrary.Files.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName
                                           (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName), byt, SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.CurrentUser, SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.CurrentUser, System.DateTime.Now, System.DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following piece of code:(You need to have a column for description)

```
SPFile file = mylibrary.Files.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName
                                       (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName), byt,      
             SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.CurrentUser, 
             SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.CurrentUser, 
             System.DateTime.Now, System.DateTime.Now);
file.CheckIn();

// Get a SPListItem for the document
SPListItem item = file.Item;
item.File.CheckOut();

item["Title"] = "MyFile_Name";
item["Author"] = "My_Name";

//etc…

item.Update();
item.File.CheckIn("Application generated file metadata.");
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: item["Description<your column name goes here>"] = "Description goes here";                       this line shows error as its a sharepoint bject i can assign any string to it , kindly let me know how to assign string to it

Comment: I updated the code block which was confusing, have a look and give it a try